# Random number using nextInt inclusive 5-15 [Java]

Tags: java

Im wondering how to generate a random number in Java inclusive between 5-15

I have

```
Random random = new Random();
int count = random.nextInt(10) + 5;
```

Comment: `int count = random.nextInt(10 + 1) + 5;` because `nextInt(int)` returns a value **exclusive** of the `int` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.nextInt(N)` will give you a random integer ranging from 0 to N-1. If you want it from 5 to 15, the range on that is 15-5+1 which is 11.

You would need to use `random.nextInt(11)` to set the range from [0,11) which is [0,10] and then add a +5 to shift it over to [5,15].

```
int count = random.nextInt(11) + 5;
```